# htaccess rewriting from one link to another link same directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can i redirect my site from this

```
http://www.mysite.org/forum/posts/129731/
```

to

```
http://www.mysite.org/forum/showthread.php?p=129731
```

and

```
http://www.mysite.org/forum/threads/hey-yall.12875
```

to

```
http://www.mysite.org/forum/showthread.php?t=12875
```

thanks

edit:

```
http://pastebin.com/La5Vf5vH
```

Added the htaccess please check. i was not able to add the code so pasted it in pastebin

Answer (score 0):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` (if not already enabled) and then put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(forum)/posts/([0-9]+)/?$ /$1/showthread.php?p=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^(forum)/threads/(?:[^.]+\.)?([0-9]+)/?$ /$1/showthread.php?t=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Post your complete .htaccess in your question, you might have existing rules in there.

Comment: checked it and there is nothing wrong. Do you have any other .htaccess  may be in `/forum/` directory?

Comment: Nope Do I need to paste your code in /forum/.htaccess or in main public_html folder?

Comment: This code is for DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess only but make sure mod_rewrite and .htaccess are enabled and you have no other .htaccess anywhere.

Comment: I have tried that but still it doesnt work. There are no htaccess in the folder.

Comment: Try to add R flag as: `RewriteRule ^(forum)/posts/([0-9]+)/?$ /$1/showthread.php?p=$2 [L,QSA,NC,R]` and see if that changes the URL.

Comment: Well that means probably your .htaccess is not being read. Can you make sure it is enabled.